# Javascript - append object to an existing key within an existing object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

Within my app, I have an object with the following structure

```
object = {"chatid1": {"messageId1": {message: "hello", id: 293839}, "messageId2": {message: "test", id: 2929292}}, "chatid2": {"messageId1": {message: 'hello', id: 292}}
```

I want to append a new message object (with its own key, e.g `"messageId3"`) to a particular `chatId`. The result operation should mean that in the example above, `"chatid1"`, should now look like the following:

```
"chatid1": {"messageId1": {message: "hello", id: 293839}, "messageId2": {message: "test", id: 2929292}, "messageId3": {message: "newMessage", id: 292121356}}
```

I tried to add the following code, however instead of appending an object, it replaced the value of whatever `object[chatId]` was.

Here is the code:

```
object[chatId] = {...object[chatId], messageToAdd}
```

`messageToAdd` has the following structure:

```
{"messageId3": {message: "newMessage", id: 2920222}}
```

How can I accomplish the task of appending to the object stored at the location `chatId`, instead of replacing it completely. Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for `Object.assign(object[chatid], messageToAdd)`? Do you need to create a new object?

Comment: @Bergi No, I would like to keep the existing object, however just append to the existing object which is the value of `object[chatId]`

Comment: That's what `Object.assign` does, it keeps the existing object and just adds the `messageId3` property from `messageToAdd` to it

Comment: @Bergi Perfect, thank you.

Comment: @Bergi  I also need the ability to do the same thing, however instead of inserting an object like you showed with your answer, deleting an object with a specific message id/key. E.g remove `messageId1` from the example in my original question. How could i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is probably what you are missing...

```
object[chatId] = { ...object[chatId], ...messageToAdd };
```

Comment: I also need the ability to do the same thing, however instead of inserting an object like you showed with your answer, deleting an object with a specific message id/key. E.g remove `messageId1` from the example in my original question. How could i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't spread the `messageToAdd` object, which led to replacing the value instead of appending the new message object. By using the spread operator on `messageToAdd`, you're correctly merging the two objects.

Also, to remove an object with a specific message ID/key, you can use the ***[`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)*** keyword.

```js
let object = {
  "chatid1": {
    "messageId1": {
      message: "hello",
      id: 293839
    },
    "messageId2": {
      message: "test",
      id: 2929292
    }
  },
  "chatid2": {
    "messageId1": {
      message: "hello",
      id: 292
    }
  }
};

const chatId = "chatid1";
const messageToAdd = {
  "messageId3": {
    message: "newMessage",
    id: 2920222
  }
};

object[chatId] = { ...object[chatId],
  ...messageToAdd
}; // This one

console.log(object);

console.log("---------OBJECT AFTER DELETION--------------");

const chatIdForDeletion = "chatid1"; // You can skip this since this is defined above but just for example sake I used it.
const messageIdToRemove = "messageId1";

if (object[chatIdForDeletion] && object[chatIdForDeletion][messageIdToRemove]) {
  delete object[chatIdForDeletion][messageIdToRemove];
}

console.log(object);
```

Comment: I also need the ability to do the same thing, however instead of inserting an object like you showed with your answer, deleting an object with a specific message id/key. E.g remove `messageId1` from the example in my original question. How could i accomplish this?